# Browserify Globals and Sharing State

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, browserify

So I'm very new to Browserify and I understand the basics of it but I wrote a whole application in Coffeescript and now need to integrate Browserify. That's not been a problem in terms of the classes and modules(my static classes) but when it comes to global variables. So like a Person class has a method that edits a buckets variable. Before when everything was in one file everyone could access it but I don't know how to do it in Browserify. Like if I do:

```
modules.export.buckets = Abuckets
```

and then later do

```
Bbuckets = require "/buckets".buckets //A and B so I can talk about them below
```

if I change buckets will it change it for everyone. Like lets say its a number and I add 3 to it, will this change be everywhere or only for my Bbuckets? If so how do I use a global variable that multiple things can access and change? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it will change it for everyone (though I think you’ll have to do `require('/buckets').buckets`).

Comment: I don't understand how exactly you want to change what, but `require` caches a module, so it's guaranteed that a module's code is only executed once. Whether changes to an exported variable affects callers depends on the type of the value, how exactly it is used, etc. E.g. a number is immutable, so change `buckets` at some point later one will not affect any callers.